# How to prevent Google Closure Compiler from removing a line

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I have a function where I create a test element. Before returning the function I'm nullifying the reference to the test element to help prevent a memory leak. But the [closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) is removing that line b/c it thinks it's not needed (in both modes). Is there some kind of [comment](http://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler) that I can add to prevent the line from being removed?

```
function isExample (testElem) {
 var bool; 
 testElem = testElem || document.createElement('div');

 // Do stuff in here to determine `bool`
 // ...

 // Then nullify the reference
 testElem = null; // The compiler removes this line. How do I make it keep it?

 return bool;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not needed. The garbage collector will do the same, so Google Closure Compiler just removes it.

I don't know of *any* garbage collector that leaks memory on this, JS would have pretty big problems if there were.

Remember that JS has function scope, which means that any variable defined in a function will be garbage collected once the execution gets out of the function.

This is one of the basic functions of the garbage collector, this'd be seriously bad if a js engine would leak memory on this.

For old IE leaks, you may try to work around the compiler by adding `testElement = []` after nullifying it.

Comment: Memory leaks are an issue in old IE. jQuery and Modernizr both nullify elements in certain functions—there has to be a reason for it.

Comment: Note that it doesn't apply to functions that create closures since now the variable must be kept alive because the closure can access it even after the original function has returned. This is not the case in the OP though, so +1 :)

Comment: @ryanve it leaks memory in old IE for events listeners on removed DOM elements, not for cases like this :-)

Comment: @Esailija yeah, there is no closure there, it's why I specified `any variable defined in a function` :p

Comment: The tests aren't shown in the example so you can't know the 'case.' Anyway I'm not trying to figure out whether the line is needed. I'm trying to figure out how to annotate to the compiler not to remove it.

Comment: Assigning an empty array to a variable shouldn't work - the compiler would still be free to remove that as dead code. If for some reason it does work, it would be considered a bug and subject to future removal.

Comment: @ryanve If the compiler is removing the value in the presence of function closures that reference the value, then this is a bug in the compiler.  If there are no closures then the compiler is free to remove the value and you should let it.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the compiler is correct. However, if you are dead set on keeping the code, then you'll need to use quoted syntax to either export the value or use a sink object.

```
function sinkValue(x) {
  sinkValue[' '](x);
  return x;
}
sinkValue[' '] = function(){};

function isExample (testElem) {
  var bool;
  var obj = { 'elem': testElem || document.createElement('div') };

  // Do stuff in here to determine `bool`
  // ...

  obj['elem'] = null;
  sinkValue(obj);

  return bool;
}
```

Quoted syntax prevents both renaming and dead-code elimination so you'll be negating any of those optimizations on that object property. In this case though you are extending the life of your object beyond the function (which seems to be the reverse of your intent).

There is no annotation to specify exactly what you want. You can see the discussions related to this at:

- ["el.offsetWidth;" wrongly treated as having no side effects](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=398)
- [Preserving Side-effects of normally side-effect-free functions](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=687)

The compiler is doing exactly what is intended in that it is removing useless code.

Comment: Chad, the object is unescaped so if this does work, it may still be eliminated in the future. Using the global window rather than obj would work but is definitely over kill.

Comment: Yeah I was worried about that. Both seem overkill. It seems like for a case like this you would need to copy in the goog.reflect.sinkValue definition. I'll modify the answer appropriately.